# сколько дней в неделе и месяце для очереди проверок?

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок

как известно, в любой из очередей проверок можно сделать не более двадцати проверок за сутки.

за неделю их можно сделать не более 140. верно? нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ну, ладно. пусть будет неделя длиной 8 суток.

но за месяц (ну, пусть это будут 31 сутки) можно сделать не более 620 проверок. верно? опять нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в месяце может быть и 26 суток!

---

первая картинка — из очереди проверок [сообщений низкого качества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats):

- за сегодня 20
- за неделю 160
- за месяц 620

вторая картинка — из очереди проверок [вопросов на закрытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats)

- за сегодня 20
- за неделю 160
- за месяц 520

---

**обновление**: для получения данных, приведённых на картинках, можно использовать http-запрос (даже без аутентификации):

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/user-info/очередь/пользователь
```

- идентификатор очереди можно посмотреть в исходниках [страницы проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review):

```
data-review-task="очередь"
```

- идентификатор пользователя — везде, где он упоминается (например, данный вопрос задан от имени пользователя с идентификатором 178576)

Comment: 520 < 620 - что не так?

Comment: [Давнишняя проблема](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166143/339911)

Comment: @Qwertiy, в этой очереди за «месяц» больше не набрать. понаблюдайте: я каждый день делаю по двадцать проверок. в таком же темпе идёт ещё 0xdb. сравните.

Comment: @Qwertiy у Александра не может быть меньше максимума! :)

Comment: Не знаю, как здесь, а на enSO есть (кажется, до сих пор) глюк, и-за которого иногда можно сделать 40 проверок вместо 20. Именно сделать можно - у меня такое много раз было.

Comment: Текущий день, вероятно, не учитывается.

Comment: @Dmitry, там в очереди для закрытия лимит повышен: слишком длинная очередь.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не учитывается **где**? любая очередная проверка увеличивает на единицу все четыре счётчика: за сегодня, за неделю, за месяц, всего.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Да? А как это определяется? У меня работало так: проверяю 20 сообщений, потом "вы проверили 20 сообщений, приходите завтра", потом в течение дня кликаю время от времени по ссылке, и дальше рандомно то проверка начинается, то опять "вы проверили 20 сообщений, приходите завтра".

Comment: @Dmitry, не знаю подробностей. посмотрите вопросы по этому поводу: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=review+limit+40